# JavaScript not working from a project I am recreating

Tags: javascript, html, css

As part of learning to code, I am recreating a project. On click of the images, they should change the main product that is appearing plus its color. May I know what I am doing wrong?

This is how it looks, but when I press one of the products nothing happens:

[image: How it looks, but when I press one of the products nothing happens]

Code:

```html
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="textbox">
            <h2>It's not just Coffee<br>It's <span>Starbucks</span></h2>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
                fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
                sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img src="img/img1.png" class="starbucks"
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="thumb">
        <li><img src="img/thumb1.png" onclick="imgSlider('img1.png');changeCircleColor('#017143')"></li>
        <li><img src="img/thumb2.png" onclick="imgSlider('img2.png');changeCircleColor('#eb7495')"></li>
        <li><img src="img/thumb3.png" onclick="imgSlider('img3.png');changeCircleColor('#d752b1')"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sci">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/instagram.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function imgSlider(anything){
        document.querySelector('.starbucks').src = anything;
    }

    function changeCircleColor(color){
        const circle = document.querySelector ('circle');
        circle.style.background = color;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your original source of the big image appears to be `img/img1.png`, but your imgSlider function assigns `imgX.png` without any path.

Comment: `const circle = document.querySelector ('circle')` - there is no element with the _tag name_ `circle` anywhere, so this selects nothing.

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns a list of elements, not a single element. Perhaps you want to iterate through it or use `document.getElementById` instead?

Comment: your HTML is not valid and you did not close the starbucks image tags on the page

Comment: Please learn to use your browser console during development, because both those issues should have caused entries in there.

Comment: @CoderCharmander That is incorrect. querySelectorAll returns a collection

Comment: `document.querySelector ('.circle');` will select the first element on the page with `class="circle"` is that what you wanted? Then you need something with the `class="circle"`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to read about `data-attribute`, because it really makes your code clear and readable and also maintainable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

But before I make the modification in your code let's see the bugs that in your code.

1. You forget to add `.` to the className in `querySelector`

```js
// Wrong
document.querySelector ('circle');

// Right way
document.querySelector('.circle')
```

2. The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector, **or group of selectors**. If no matches are found, null is returned, in your code it will return a group of selectors.

Now let's make your code works.

1. Make a function that will handle the `onclick` event.

> About javaScript events: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

```js
function handleImageClick(event) {
// @TODO add your logic here.
}
```

2. Add two `data-attribute` to each image which are `data-image=""` and `data-color=""` and also class the event handler that we already made

```html
<ul class="thumb">
  <li><img src="img/thumb1.png" onclick="handleImageClick(this)" data-image="img1.png" data-color="#017143"></li>
  <li><img src="img/thumb2.png" onclick="handleImageClick(this)" data-image="img2.png" data-color="#eb7495"></li>
  <li><img src="img/thumb3.png" onclick="handleImageClick(this)" data-image="img3.png" data-color="#d752b1"></li>
</ul>
```

3. Let's write the logic

```js
function handleImageClick(event) {
  var target = event;
  
  // Get the color and the image from data-attribute
  var color = target.dataset.color;
  var image = target.dataset.image;
  
  // Checkout the console
  console.log(color, image)
  
  target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  target.src  = image;
}
```

Live Example: https://codepen.io/nawafscript/pen/eYEKBJJ

Hope my explanation is clear.